# How to hide message content in notifications of One Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I tried to use the new [One Outlook](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/getting-started-with-the-new-outlook-for-windows-656bb8d9-5a60-49b2-a98b-ba7822bc7627) and though it is kind of wobbly yet (details can be found [here](https://petri.com/microsoft-new-outlook-for-windows-office-insiders/)), it has potential.

Unfortunately, the notifications are quite hard to customize, as I can only set of what I want to get notifications about (messages and/or events) and the rest is handled by Windows.

[image]

So when I get an important mail, my screen shows the message like this:

[image]

It can be quite unfortunate if someone is at my desk and also reads the message.

Can I somehow hide the content? By Outlook or Windows settings?

Answer (score 1):

> Can I somehow hide the content? By Outlook or Windows settings?

No, not feasible at present.

Currently, the notification settings for new messages in New Outlook are limited to options below and none of them can be used to hide the content:

- Within the New Outlook:
  [image]
- Windows settings:
  [image]

Given this, in order to avoid the dilemma you mentioned above, I'd suggest just turning off the notification banner in Windows settings and make sure the sound notification is enabled in the New Outlook app.
[image]

[image]

In this way, you'll be able to hear the sound when a new mail come in and see the blue icon which stands for new notification in the lower right corner of your screen, click on it and you can see the details in the message center.

[image]

In addition, I'd recommend sending a feature request via Help > Feedback. Hopefully this feature can be added in the future update.

[image]

Comment: It's a nice workaround though basically you replied that it can't be done _at the moment_. I upvote your answer, but leave the question open until a true solution is found.

Comment: Okay. Understood :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use the generic Windows Notifications & actions settings page, to toggle notifications from the application

[image]

Comment: This is not enough, it can set the following: show notifications on the taskbar and/or the notification area, hide content **on the lock screen** and play a sound. Why would I hide the content _only on the lock screen_?

Comment: "hide content on the lock screen", as well as, not instead of. It's all of those things.